# Update multiple value postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue when I try to update multiple rows with this request

```
update redux.rentalpivots tg
set (maxleasedatebymonth) = (select a.maxleasedatebymonth 
                             from redux.rental_latest_lease a,
                                  redux.rentalpivots b 
                             where a.surfaceid = b.surfaceid
                               and a.startdate = b.startdate
                               and b.enabled = TRUE 
                               and a.maxleasedatebymonth = b.leasestartdate
                               and tg.surfaceid = b.surfaceid
                               and tg.startdate = b.startdate 
                               and tg.enabled = b.enabled and b.surfaceid =  ?  )
 WHERE surfaceid = ?
```

that's return :

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: more than one row returned
>   by a subquery used as an expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `UPDATE FROM ..` syntax, something like:

```
update redux.rentalpivots tg
  set maxleasedatebymonth = x.maxleasedatebymonth
from redux.rental_latest_lease a
where tg.surfaceid = a.surfaceid
  and tg.startdate = a.startdate 
  and tg.leasestartdate = a.maxleasedatebymonth 
  and tg.enabled
  and tg.surfaceid = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably intend a correlated subquery.  I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but the query should look more like this:

```
update redux.rentalpivots tg
    set maxleasedatebymonth = (select a.maxleasedatebymonth 
                               from redux.rental_latest_lease rll 
                               where rll.surfaceid = tg.surfaceid and
                                     rll.startdate = tg.startdate and
                                     rll.maxleasedatebymonth = tg.leasestartdate
                              )
     where tg.enabled and tg.surfaceid = ?;
```

If you still have a problem, you can get around the issue by adding `limit 1` to the subquery.

That said, if you think only one row should match and multiple rows match, you should figure out why and fix your data.